# Alkali metal hydrides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends

I know that stability of alkali metal hydrides decreases down the group,Hence the lowest member in the group easily breaks into its cation but does this easiness of breaking into cation has any relation with its reducing nature.I also wanted to know what is order of reducing character in alkali metal group?

Answer (score 2):

Alkali metal hydrides can typically be viewed as labile hydride anions. The extent of lability can correlate with the electronegativity of the metal. Hence, less electronegative metals in alkali metal hydrides yield more labile hydride anions and more "reducing" nature.